# Differences between energy level and end energy state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, definition, eigenvalue, quantum-states

What is differences between energy level and end energy state in quantum mechanic?
Are they same?
Is the energy state same as the quantum state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do electrons in same orbital shell (ex: $3p$) have the same energy level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/716516/)

Comment: Actually, do energy state and quantum state have the same meaning?

Comment: No they aren't. If you had read my answer in the link above, you'd know...